# Sharing An Image In Windows Phone Using NFC

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, nfc

I am on a Image Editing project. Its a WP8 based project. What I want is that the application to accept an image as an Input from the NFC(other device). I want to have a button click event clicking on which gets me the image.
secondly I also want that after editing the Pic , I can share it using NFC .I would use an application bar and provide a icon for sharing the image.
Help needed. Completely novoice in NFC !!

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PixPresenter-Code-sharing-39ed631f

Comment: unalble to understand the implementation. I want line by line solution as i am completely new to it. i need to take an image through NFC as input and then edit it and then finally share the final image using NFC i want to have buttons for receiving and sharing the pic

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP 8 NFC File Transfer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500992/wp-8-nfc-file-transfer)

Answer (score 0):

please see my previous answer to a similar question on the topic of NFC file transfers @ [WP 8 NFC File Transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500992/wp-8-nfc-file-transfer/13501880#13501880)

The short version is that NFC isn't a good fit for file transfers, but you can use NFC to open sockets to other WP8/Win8 devices.

Comment: but its too long to understand..i need step by step implementation sir

Comment: There's a link to a code sample at the end of that 3 paragraph forum post.